# Add validation to a filter textfield in an EXT-JS 4.1 GridPanel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have an EXT-JS grid panel with remote filtering:

```
Ext.define('My.GridPanel', {
   extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel'

   ...

   features: [{
      ftype: 'filters'
      encode: true,
      local: false
   }],
   initComponent: function() {
      ....

   .....
});
```

How can I add validation to the textfield that's created which allows you to enter the filtering criteria?

What I want to do is disallow certain characters that are causing bad things to happen on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a searchfield  and verify its value before sending it

```
dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock: 'top',
                    height : 30,
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'searchfield',
                            width: 400,
                            fieldLabel: 'Search ',
                            labelWidth: 60,
                            store: gridStore,
                            listeners:{
                                change:function(element, value){
                                    console.log(value);
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                                          ]
                               }
               ]
```